# /Users/Me/.zshrc:1: unmatched `

Tags: zsh

I getting this error in my console which is breaking zsh:

```
/Users/Me/.zshrc:1: unmatched `
```

I can't find that unmatched char anywhere in the `.zshrc` file. In fact, if I completely empty the file and reload my console, the error still comes up.

My `.zshrc` file:

```
# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh

fpath=(/usr/local/share/zsh-completions $fpath)
fpath=($(brew --prefix)/share/zsh/site-functions $fpath)

# Set name of the theme to load.
# Look in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/
# Optionally, if you set this to "random", it'll load a random theme each
# time that oh-my-zsh is loaded.
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks.
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# The optional three formats: "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(git)

# User configuration

export PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$HOME/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# ssh
# export SSH_KEY_PATH="~/.ssh/dsa_id"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"

# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
export NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node"
export PATH="/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/sbin"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/postgresql@10/bin:$PATH"

if [ -f ~/.aliases ]; then
    . ~/.aliases
fi
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Please share the URL for your starting template example.  What is your OS and version of zsh?

Comment: Are you sure there's no stray backtick on the first line of your `.zshrc`? The only error I get from the code as posted is on line 58, as I don't have `oh-my-zsh.sh` to source.

Comment: @chepner I can empty the entire file and I still get the error.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Mac Catalina and ZSH v5.8. https://ohmyz.sh/

Comment: How did you install 5.8? That isn't what ships with Catalina.

Comment: I used `homebrew` to upgrade

Comment: My opinion is you need to remove the . after the slash in the first setting you have listed.